# Connecting to Mac OSX using an Android phone

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth

I am writing some code to connect my Android device to my Mac using bluetooth. Its seems to create a connection,(i am able to see my android in tbe connected list in Mac) But it throws an exception on the android device.

```
BluetoothDevice bd = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("00:26:08:BF:D0:22");
BluetoothSocket bs = null;
try {
    bs = bd.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(DeviceSearchService.MY_UUID);
    try {
       bs.connect();

     } catch (IOException ex) {
       Log.i(TAG, "Exception in connecting to socket." + ex.getMessage(), ex);
     }
}
```

The bs.connect is throwing an exception saying cannot connect to the device. The device in question is a Mac OSX laptop of mine. I am running this code from Galaxy S device.
THe UUID used is "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

have you declared the Bluetooth permissions in your application manifest file?

```
<manifest ... >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: yes I have that permission. I am able to discover, send pairing requests etc.